# A more complex selection

Tags: css, css-selectors

not so long ago i found out that you can do this in css ( the use of ">" ) :

```
#viewCounterFix > .hourMinSec > .hour > .devider ,
#viewCounterFix > .hourMinSec > .min > .devider ,
#viewCounterFix > .hourMinSec > .sec > .devider{
    left: 24px;
}
```

Now , in the example above as you can see , i need the exact same thing and the only diference is  .hour, .min, .sec .

I was wondering if there is a shorter way to do this ?
Maybe something like:

```
#viewCounterFix > .hourMinSec > [.sec or .min or .hour] > .devider{
    left: 24px;
}
```

So does such syntax exist ?

EDIT : 
Here is the full structure

```
<div class="hourMinSec">
    <div class="hour">
        <span class="leftHour">1</span><div class="devider"></div><span class="rightHour">1</span>
    </div>
    <img class="leftClockDots" src="/bids/images/dots.png">
    <div class="min">
        <span class="leftMin">3</span><div class="devider"></div><span class="rightMin">5</span>
    </div>
    <img class="rightClockDots" src="/bids/images/dots.png">
    <div class="sec">
        <span class="leftSec">0</span><div class="devider"></div><span class="rightSec">1</span>
    </div>
    <span class="time"><span class="hourText">hour</span><span class="minText">min</span><span class="secText">sec</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With standard CSS, your method is the best option.

It is not possible to have a vary of classes in the middle of a CSS rule.

However, if `.sec`, `.min`, `.hour` are the only elements which will be in `.hourMinSec`, you could ommit this from your CSS rule:

```
#viewCounterFix > .hourMinSec .devider {
    left: 24px;
}
```

Comment: .sec .min and .hour are not the only elements in .hourMinSec but it stil worked ,  i will edit my question and post the sturcture.

Comment: @Jordashiro It will still work, but it also apply this style to any `.devider` classes that are not in min/sec/hour

Comment: Oh ok , i misunderstood what you ment. Thank you for your help , works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately such syntax does not exist in css, but you could add another class to your `.hour` `.min` and `.sec` elements like `.foo`

and then have

```
#viewCounterFix > .hourMinSec > .foo > .devider {
    left: 24px;
}
```

if you don't need that specificity, you could omit one selector:

```
#viewCounterFix > .hourMinSec .devider {
    left: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Such syntax will exist in CSS4, and exists now in some browsers:

The `:-moz-any()` / `:-webkit-any()` selector:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A-moz-any
- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/05/moz-any-selector-grouping/

CSS4's `:matches()` selector

- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches

BTW, if `.hourMinSec` contains nothing else, just those three numbers, then you could use `*`:

```
#viewCounterFix > .hourMinSec > * > .devider {
    left: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exist, but you may add a class on the `.sec`, `.min` and `.hour`, let say `.time` and bo this :

```
#viewCounterFix > .hourMinSec > .time > .devider{
    left: 24px;
}
```

Comment: I know that will work but i don't want to add any more classes/IDs , thats why i took this aproach.